# Postgresql - Creating a bitmap index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, bitmap

Bitmap index:

```
  CREATE TABLE customer
    (
     customerid character varying(20) NOT NULL,
     title character varying(40),
     country character varying(100),
     phone character varying(50))
```

I have this table customer and i want to create a bitmap index on title and country... how can i do it?

Comment: To my knowledge, postgres doesn't have a bitmap index type. Can you explain what you're trying to do, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32112397/3886053, also info about bitmap indexes here http://stackoverflow.com/q/33100637/3886053

Comment: i want to create a bitmap index using title and country as a field, i have a different titles and countries and i want to create an bitmapindex like there is in oracle